# Column menu items list customization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, syncfusion

Currently, I'm investigating SyncFusion grid [syncfusion-ej2](http://ej2.syncfusion.com/15.4.23/angular/documentation/) for Angular 2 and found great feature - to turn on column menu to have all controls (sort, group, filter) in one place.

But it's not enough for my needs and I'm looking for the ways to customize the list of items in column menu, e.g. I want to be able to add my items with custom actions to react on click/select user actions.

For example, I want to add an item to hide current column directly or to pin this column.

Could you please tell me if it's possible and how to implement it if it is? Or I should create a custom component for this manipulations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should upgrade to version 5. Version 2 is over a year old and contains a lot of deprecated modules.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. We using latest Angular version. But still, if it possible to manipulate SyncFusion grid in such way using Angular 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, guys, I found a solution for my question in the TypeScript section of documentation right [here](http://ej2.syncfusion.com/15.4.23/documentation/grid/columns.html?lang=typescript#custom-column-menu-item)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work right now like it showed in the demo. But they said that already [fixed](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-grids/issues/5) this problem and the release will be today, January 10, 2018.

Here is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQv8DaG6Jqj8I2CqLgmi?p=preview) of TypeScript version.

```
import { Grid, ColumnMenu, Sort, Page } from '@syncfusion/ej2-grids';
import { MenuEventArgs } from '@syncfusion/ej2-navigations';
import { data  } from './datasource.ts';

Grid.Inject(ColumnMenu, Page, Sort);
// The problem is in the base constant value
// columnMenuClick should have a value "columnMenuClick"
// but it has a value "contextMenuClick" like contextMenuClick constant for context menu
let grid: Grid = new Grid({
    dataSource: data,
    allowPaging: true,
    allowSorting: true,
    showColumnMenu: true,
    columnMenuItems:[{text:'Clear Sorting', id:'gridclearsorting'}],
    contextMenuClick: function(args: MenuEventArgs){
        if(args.item.id === 'gridclearsorting'){
            grid.clearSorting();
        }
    },
    sortSettings:{
        columns:[{direction: "ascending", field: "OrderID"}]
    },
    columns: [
        { field: 'OrderID', headerText: 'Order ID', width: 200, textAlign: 'right', showInColumnChooser: false },
        { field: 'Freight', width: 150, format: 'C2', textAlign: 'right', editType: 'numericedit' },
        { field: 'ShipName', headerText: 'Ship Name', width: 300 },
        { field: 'ShipCountry', headerText: 'Ship Country', visible: false, width: 200 },
        { field: 'ShipCity', headerText: 'Ship City', width: 200 }
    ]
});
grid.appendTo('#Grid');
```

Here is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jn3khKnQnqpRVYW8nyyF?p=preview) of Angular 4 version.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SortService, ResizeService, GroupService, ColumnMenuService, PageService, FilterService } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';
import { ContextMenuItem, GroupSettingsModel, FilterSettingsModel, EditSettingsModel, ColumnMenuItemModel } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';
import { GridComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';
import { MenuEventArgs } from '@syncfusion/ej2-navigations';
import { data } from './data';

@Component({
    selector: 'control-content',
    templateUrl: 'columnmenu.html',

})
export class ColumnMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    public data: Object[];
    public groupOptions: GroupSettingsModel;
    public filterSettings: FilterSettingsModel;
    public columnMenuItems: ColumnMenuItemModel[];
    @ViewChild('grid')
    public grid: GridComponent;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.data = data.slice(0, 60);
        this.groupOptions = { showGroupedColumn: true };
        this.filterSettings = { type: 'checkbox' };
        this.columnMenuItems = [{text:'Clear Sorting', id:'gridclearsorting'}];
    }

    public columnMenuClick(args: MenuEventArgs): void {
    console.log('123');
      if(args.item.id === 'gridclearsorting'){
            this.grid.clearSorting();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Essential JS 2 Grid v 15.4.24 has been released and the issue fix for “The context menu event triggering” was included. Please find the below-working plunker sample.

```
columnMenuClick(args){
    if(args.item.id === 'gridclearsorting'){
        this.grid.clearSorting();
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZQxv8JCUzcv2NEYg3MI?p=preview)

In that sample, We have added custom column menu option to clear Grid sorting.